# Why is box-sizing for <button> "border-box" by default?

Tags: css

On https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#values I read that `content-box` should be the default `box-content` mode ("as specified by the CSS standard"). However, for `<button>`, I see `border-box` (both in the devtools and in the rendered result) both in Chrome and Firefox.

I use the following HTML to test it. Why are the green areas not the same length?
I noticed that `<button>` has `display: inline-block` and thought that may be related, but no – even if I set the same `display` for a `<div>`, it still doesn't change the `box-sizing` automatically.

```html
<html>
  <style>div, button {background: green; width: 100px; padding: 0 30px;}</style>
  <body>
    <div>ha</div>
    <button>bu</button><br>
    <div style="display: inline-block">ga</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is something called user agent stylesheet where browsers specify "common sense" defaults for html elements. E.g. the css spec say the _initial_ value for display is inline so how come all divs are block? It is the ua stylesheet where these overrides are defined and probably the same place where it is defined that buttons should use a sans serif font and box sizing should be border box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN has this to say:

> [box-sizing - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
> `box-sizing: border-box` is the default styling that browsers use for the `<table>`, `<select>`, and `<button>` elements, and for `<input>` elements whose type is `radio`, `checkbox`, `reset`, `button`, `submit`, `color`, or `search`.

This is documented in the standards:

> [CSS Box Sizing Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing/#box-sizing)
> Note: Certain HTML elements, such as `button`, default to `border-box` behavior.

So technically, the "why" is because it's what the standards say it <del>should be</del> is expected to be *(see Alohci's comment below)*.

If you want to know why the standards say that, you may be able to find the answer buried in [the W3C mailing list archives](https://www.w3.org/Mail/Archives).

Comment: This is incorrect. The CSS specs do not say _it should be_.

Comment: @SalmanA Which specs are you looking at? Both MDN and the CSSWG say that `<button>` elements use `border-box` by default. [The W3C page](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-sizing-3/#box-sizing) says exactly the same.

Comment: I emphasized on _should_. Also it is written in green box so it cannot be treated as an instruction to e.g. browser vendor. MDN data is based on specs so it cannot be cited as original source.

Comment: @SalmanA - It is the HTML5 spec that says that [border-box](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#form-controls) is [_expected to be_](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#rendering) used for button elements.

Comment: @RichardDeeming - The standard says that because it follows from backward compatibility with how the dimensions had to be interpreted when form controls were replaced elements, and the border and padding widths were determined outside of CSS's purview.

Comment: @RichardDeeming , thank you! I didn't read the whole text of the MDN text carefully. They mention the different default for buttons in the description section but not in the "values" section, so I missed it. And thank you for the W3C link! Although they are not very specific about which elements have which defaults and mentions some "HTML" to look for details ("See HTML for details on which elements have this behavior.") :D .

Answer (score 1):

Changing the display property will not affect the box-sizing property.

It explicitly mentioned in MDN that border-box is the default for box-sizing in the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

In the ha and ga box(1st and the 3rd). It is div, so box-sizing defaults to content-box which means

```
content-width = 100px
padding-left = 30px
padding-right = 30px
```

which implies that,

```
total-width = 100px + 30px + 30px = 160px
```

While in the bu box(2nd box) the box-sizing defaults to border-box, which means

```
total-width = 100px
padding-left = 30px
padding-right = 30px
```

which implies that,

```
content-width = 100px - 30px - 30px = 40px
```

please feel free to reference the BOX model diagram (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) to follow the following,

In border-box,

```
width = content-width + padding-left + padding-right + border-left + border-right
```

while in content-box,

```
width = content-width
```

So you can choose your box-sizing property accordingly to fit your requirement.

Comment: You're pointing to the same link I have already referenced in the question, so it doesn't really help. That page has statements like "content-box gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior." and "content-box This is the initial and default value as specified by the CSS standard.", which seem to contradict with your "It explicitly mentioned in MDN that border-box is the default for box-sizing in the docs".

Comment: No, it doesn't contradict kindly check the border-box section on the page which is slightly above the Note section in that link, which is highlighted in blue. 

It says "box-sizing: border-box is the default styling that browsers use for the <table>, <select>, and <button> elements, and for <input> elements whose type is radio, checkbox, reset, button, submit, color, or search."

Normally content-box would be the default one for most of the HTML tags but for certain HTML tags, border-box is the default one.

Comment: Yes, I'd missed that note. Still, their doc does include the two opposed statements I quoted, so it is confusing for non-through readers like me. Thank you for the extra explanation!